# Can somebody help me: if $a^b = 2015^{2016}-2015^{2015}$ so, $a-b$ =?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

an somebody please help me

$a^b = 2015^{2016} - 2015^{2015}$

So, $a-b =  ... $

it is written in my text book but I cant seem to get it

Comment: Are $a,b$ assumed to be (positive) integers?

Comment: I suspect you've transcribed the problem incorrectly somewhere, but it's worth noting: $2015^{2016} = 2015\cdot 2015^{2015}$...

Answer (score 7):

(If there is no restriction that $a$ and $b$ are integers, then this problem has uncountably many solutions, which would be odd in this context. The following answer is based on the restriction to solutions among the natural numbers.)

Why don't we simplify the right-hand side a bit:

$$\begin{align}
N=2015^{2016}-2015^{2015} &= 2015\cdot 2015^{2015}-2015^{2015}\\
&= (2015-1)2015^{2015}\\
&= 2014\cdot2015^{2015}
\end{align}$$

Now, let's factor those integers: $2014=2\cdot 19\cdot 53$, and $2015=5\cdot 13\cdot 31$.

Thus, the prime factorization of our number is:

$$N=2^1\cdot 19^1\cdot 53^1\cdot 5^{2015}\cdot 13^{2015}\cdot 31^{2015}$$

In the prime factorization of $a^b$, every power must be a multiple of $b$, so in this case we have $b=1$, and the only way to write $N$ as an integer power is:

$$N=N^1$$

thus making $a-b=N-1=2014\cdot2015^{2015}-1$.

---

The fact that this answer isn't nicer makes me wonder if the comment above is correct, that maybe there's a transcription error here?

Comment: Just saying, but this relies on the assumption of $a,b$ being positive integers, which the question does not state. Otherwise $b = \log_a 2014 \cdot 2015^{2015}$ works for all $a \gt 0, a \ne 1$.

Comment: Yeah, it comes from the assumption that the question is anything close to well-posed. If there aren't intended to be uncountably many solutions, then it's a Diophantine equation.

Comment: Either the question or the `logarithms` tag is wrong. Which one, that's anybody's guess ;-)